# Communicate two modules Android

Tags: android, module, architecture

I have a module A and a module B of the same android project but in different repositories.
The module A have to send to module B an object (with drawables and behaviour), but A and B does not know each other.
My object's class is in module A, and module B does not know this class.
I tried Event Bus, but i must know the class.
Also i tried intent and content provider, but again module B must know this class
And i tried save only strings in an intent, but the module B must know every string and what it means
What can i do to communicate them?

Comment: What is a "module"?

Comment: "but the module B must know every string and what it means" -- well, yes. That is pretty much a requirement of computer programming. You might consider implementing a common library, that both A and B depend upon, so you can have some common constants, classes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a dependency between module A and module B.

Otherwise you must create an interface indipendent layer (a third module for example) that defines a well known communication structure.

Or you can use something like JSON and then parse from a unique string source.

In all cases programming without knowing the contest is not possible.